# Локальный сервер на linux

Tags: windows, веб-программирование, linux

Всем привет.

Веб-разработчикам Денвер приходиться по душе, но в мозгу у меня последнее время есть негатив к windows, и есть желание перейти на linux. Так вот, собственно, в чем дело. Кто знает, как обстоят дела там с локальным сервером, есть какие либо аналоги? Наверное, единственная причина, по которой до сих пор сижу на win-de.

Answer (score 4):

Lamp, xampp, установка голого apache, php, mysql. Рано вам пока на linux, если поисковиками пользоваться еще не научились.

Comment: Вы первый, кто пытается жаловаться на ... локальные сервера для linux,  слышал многое: photoshop, autocad, банально - игры (это может и причины остаться на windows)... Ответ дал Get, добавлю: ngix, node.js, голый php...

Comment: @shilgen: what?

Comment: @Get, на Linux никогда не рано, сразу поиском научишься пользоваться. :) @balimira: отлично обстоят дела, переходите на Linux, не пожалеете, а когда разберетесь, то не захотите обратно в объятья мелкомягкого Win.

Answer (score 2):

Denwer - это, как я понимаю, просто перенесенный на винды родной никсовый сервер Apache. Так что обстоит все самым лучшим образом.

Answer (score 1):

Там всё уже давным-давно готово. Не надо ничего ручками компилировать (не всё, но в большинстве случаев).

Answer (score 1):

Там всё намного проще, буквально 2-3 команды в терминале (а если с ним не дружите, есть менеджер программ/пакетов), и всё делается в 2-3 клика,  сервер полностью готов. Для начала советую использовать следующие дистрибутивы:

[Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/)

[Linux Mint](http://linuxmint.com/)

По ним огромное количество информации и на YouTube, и сообщество активное, я думаю, что проблем с сервером точно не будет.

[Вот ещё полезная ссылочка](http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/apachemysqlphp).